# Lift instance for a function?

Tags: haskell

I need to put a function into Template Haskell code. I am using the expression syntax:

```
[|f|]
```

Some functions seem to work automatically. However, for this particular one I get the following erroe message:

```
   No instance for (Lift (String -> [Content]))
```

I have no idea how to make a lift instance for a function, and can't seem to find any useful information. Can anyone point me to a resource or give me an idea of how this is accomplished in general? In the mean time I will see if I can pare down my specific example.

Comment: I have found the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Lift) (almost none). Hope it helps, but it probably won't :( Seems like you have to write a function `lift :: (String -> [Content]) -> Q Exp`, i.e., translate your function into an expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll take a stab, though TH can be hard to debug without seeing more code.

Let's take a look at some sample code:

**foo.hs:**

```
{-# Language TemplateHaskell #-}

baz x = let f y = x + y
    in [| f |]

bez x = let f y = x + y
    in [| \y -> f y |]

boz x = [| \y -> x + y |]

g x y = x + y

byz x = [| g x |]
```

Now we can fire this up in GHCi (I'm on version 7.0.2, which is what ships with the current Haskell Platform):

```
$ ghci foo.hs -XTemplateHaskell
*Main> :m +Language.Haskell.TH
*Main Language.Haskell.TH> runQ (baz 2)

<interactive>:1:7:
No instance for (Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Lift (a0 -> a0))
  arising from a use of `baz'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Lift (a0 -> a0))
In the first argument of `runQ', namely `(baz 2)'
In the expression: runQ (baz 2)
In an equation for `it': it = runQ (baz 2)
*Main Language.Haskell.TH> runQ (bez 2)

<interactive>:1:7:
    No instance for (Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Lift (a0 -> a0))
      arising from a use of `bez'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Lift (a0 -> a0))
    In the first argument of `runQ', namely `(bez 2)'
    In the expression: runQ (bez 2)
    In an equation for `it': it = runQ (bez 2)
*Main Language.Haskell.TH> runQ (boz 2)
LamE [VarP y_0] (InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 2))) (VarE GHC.Num.+) (Just (VarE y_0)))
*Main Language.Haskell.TH> runQ (byz 2)
AppE (VarE Main.g) (LitE (IntegerL 2))
```

What I've done here is attempted to use `runQ` to see what the TH splice looks like for each of my functions in the sample code.  It fails on `baz` and `bez`, but works for `boz` and `byz`.

Looking at the TH for `boz` and `byz`, we can see how functions are lifted: `boz` is basically just referring to `+` by name (in `VarE GHC.Num.+`), while `byz` is just referring to `g` by name (in `VarE Main.g`).

For `baz` and `bez`, this option isn't on the table: both of those functions are attempting to splice `f`, which is locally bound; hence, reference to `VarE f` wouldn't make sense outside of `baz` and `bez`.

So what's a developer to do?  In short, instead of trying `[| f |]`, you need to write the expression for `f` in the lift directly, in terms of identifiers that will be bound where the splice occurs.

On a side note, it is very easy to write `Lift` instances for algebraic data types, since you can always lift globally-defined functions.  Here's one for `Maybe`:

```
instance Lift a => Lift (Maybe a) where
  lift Nothing = [| Nothing |]
  lift (Just a) = [| Just a |]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make things work by changing things around with this new understanding of TH.