# How to create a pattern match for Int in a function taking a Type?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have a function that takes a `Type`:

```
data MyType = IntT | BoolT | OtherT

typeToMyType :: Type -> MyType
```

How can I write a pattern that would state I want to match on the type of `Int`?

### What have I tried?

#### 1

`[t| GHC.Types.Int |]` will create a value of type `Q Type`, but despite hours of struggling I was unable to force into a pattern match splice.

I've tried to use it in a guard as well:

```
| $( do tI <- [t| GHC.Types.Int |]; [| t == tI |] ) = ...
```

But that complains about:

```
No instance for (Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Lift Type)
  arising from a use of `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.lift'
In the expression: Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.lift tI
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  [| t == tI |]
  pending(rn) [tI]
In the expression:
  do { tI <- [t| Int |];
       [| t == tI |]
       pending(rn) [tI] }
```

#### 2

A perhaps simpler approach would be to:

```
typeToMyType :: Type -> MyType
typeToMyType (ConT $(''Int)) = NumberT
```

But then:

```
Couldn't match type `Name' with `Q Pat'
Expected type: PatQ
  Actual type: Name
In the expression: ''Int
In the splice: $(''Int)
```

I have no idea what that means.

### What do I (even) need it for?

I want to "parse" a function signature to create a `Q Dec`. I've used `String` for a prototype:

```
    gen ["Int", "Int"] "luaOpMinus" '-
  ======>
    Eval.hs:24:3-38
    luaOpMinus [Number x_a98F, Number x_a98G]
      = (return $ [Number ((-) x_a98F x_a98G)])
```

As you can see, it turns a function `Int -> Int -> Int`, annotated with a value `["Int", "Int"]` (I've omitted the return type for now), into a function `[LuaValue] -> LuaValue` - so that it can be called from Lua easily. Typing signatures by hand is tedious, though, so I wanted to extract that from `reify`.

The problem is that while I can read what `reify` gives me perfectly clearly:

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH Data.Bits> $(reify 'bit >>= stringE . show)
"ClassOpI Data.Bits.bit (ForallT [PlainTV a_1627400821] [ClassP Data.Bits.Bits [VarT a_1627400821]] (AppT (AppT
ArrowT (ConT GHC.Types.Int)) (VarT a_1627400821))) Data.Bits.Bits (Fixity 9 InfixL)"
```

I can't write the **`(ConT GHC.Types.Int)`** pattern.

Comment: Possibly related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618803/functions-as-arguments-to-be-used-in-template-haskell-quote

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> typeToMyType :: Type -> MyType
> typeToMyType (ConT $(''Int)) = NumberT
> ```

You don't need the `$(...)`, since `''Int` already has type `Name`.

```
typeToMyType :: Type -> MyType
typeToMyType (ConT t) | t == ''Int  = IntT
                      | t == ''Bool = BoolT
typeToMyType _ = OtherT
```

For some reason GHC doesn't like the `''Int` syntax in the pattern, so I had to move it to a pattern guard.

Comment: `''Int` is not pattern syntax, so naturally the compiler will complain if it appears in a pattern.